# Secure single sign-on for both secure and vulnerable web services

Tags: security, single-sign-on, vbulletin

I'd like to know if it is possible to have a secure single sign-on across two webservices of which 1 is more secure than the other. To be more specific, less secure would be vbulletin forum and the more secure one a webservice, where real money is earned, withdrawn etc. For the sake of convenience for the users I would like to implement a secure single sign-on, but looking at the vbulletin's security track record, especially xss vulnerabilities, even sql injection, then I'm not sure if sso will be a viable option if it would degrades security of the more secure service.

Comment: I know that I prefer solos to duets, so I'm also very interested in single sing-on. I hope you get a good answer to your question. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be permissible to use a high-assurance credential to authenticate to a low-assurance system provided that long-term shared authentication secrets are not revealed to the low-assurance system (see, e.g., NIST Special Publication 800-63, Level-2 and above).  This generally requires an assertion (e.g., SAML) from the Credential Service Provider to the Relying Party.  The CSP, which is trusted, accepts the credential and asserts its authenticity, and possibly other attributes associated with the Subscriber, to the relying party (the application), which is not trusted.  Since secret tokens associated with the credential (e.g., a password) are never sent to the relying party, a breach in that service would not provide an attacker with useful knowledge to attack the high-assurance system.  There are a number of industry standards, such as OpenID and OATH, for credential federation in this manner.

Comment: if there was a security breach in low-assurance system and the attacker would steal the session cookie of the user, wouldn't the attacker be able to use it to gain access to the high-assurance system if I used say OpenID?

Comment: No -- the attacker would only be able to impersonate the user for that application.  There is no global session; the application session is separate form any open session the user may have with the CSP.  Consequently, when the attacker tries to authenticate to the secure service, the CSP will not recognize that user and require reauthentication.  The [OpenID 2.0 Federal Profile (PDF)](http://www.idmanagement.gov/documents/ICAM_OpenID20Profile.pdf) describes this assertion process in detail.

Comment: I think this does not apply when I'm trying to run the less secure app on domain.com and the more secure one on a subdomain for example secure.domain.com. I asked a new question to investigate further if this is the case and possible workarounds - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065978/understanding-cookie-domain-relationship-with-top-level-domain-and-its-subdomains

Answer (score 0):

Stop inventing your own sign-on systems. Use [OpenID](https://openid.org/) like StackOverflow itself does. That will solve your problem neatly and your users will be hugely pleased with you for not forcing them to remember yet another password.

Comment: Who said I was trying to invent anything ;) If OpenId can what I need, then great I will most certainly use it.