# Understanding cookie domain relationship with top level domain and its subdomains

Tags: security, cookies, xss, single-sign-on, vbulletin

I have a domain with 2 subdomains like this: www.domain.com and secure.domain.com (with ssl). www subdomain will be running vbulletin (prone to xss attacks) and the webservice behind secure subdomain is well, more secure as well as more sensitive to attacks since real money is involved there. domain.com is 301 redirecting to www.domain.com. Now I'd like to have a single sign-on to both of the services without compromising the security of the secure subdomain. It seems to me there are 2 ways of doing this:

1. Using OpenID and after successful authentication, set cookie domain only to subdomains respectively, example .www.domain.com and .secure.domain.com so that secure.domain.com cookies will not be sent to the attacker in case of an intrusion in www.domain.com
2. Only enable users to log on from secure.domain.com and set 2 cookies, 1 with .domain.com for seamless authentication to www.domain.com and another cookie to .secure.domain.com to verify that the user has authenticated through secure subdomain.

My understanding is that when it comes to sso across several webapps on a single domain and its subdomains, then running any app on top level domain such as domain.com would be a potential security risk because the app on top level will always be sent all the cookies set by subdomains as well as subdomains will be able to set and receive cookies of the top level domain.

**The question is this:** Are my assumptions correct or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the cookie as `secure` and it will be sent only over SSL connections (no matter what domain the client connects to). Of course, more complicated scenarios are possible as well.

Comment: Are you saying secure cookies sent over SSL connection are not vulnerable to XSS attacks?

Comment: @jaz I am saying that when you set "secure" attribute for the cookie, it will not be sent in response to requests coming via non-secure connection. This was just a note (which you *probably* could be missing). In general your assumption is right - if the cookie grants access to both sites, then attacker can get to secure.* via www.*

Comment: yes, it seems secure cookies make cookie stealing harder via xss because the attacker would need a valid ssl certificate. I also found out about httponly cookies which which should be useful as well although not all browsers support it.